# Printing Stringstream Outputs Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, implicit-conversion, stringstream

Rather than outputting the expected string of `"Bar"`, the following code outputs what looks to be a pointer.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream Foo("Bar");
    std::cout << Foo << std::endl; // Outputs "0x22fe80."
    return 0;
}
```

This can be worked around by using `Foo.str()`, but it's caused some issues for me in the past.  What causes this strange behavior?  Where is it documented?

Comment: Since this was already answered I might as well put here what the address means, in case you're curious. Typically, to allow streams to be tested in boolean contexts operator void* is overloaded, this results (in some implementations) in code like `operator void *() const {return (fail() ? 0 : (void *)this);} ` which (if no fail flag is set) will return the address of the object itself. In some implementations this means the address of either a member of the class or the virtual table pointer, at least in vc++ it seems to do the latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This can be worked around by using Foo.str(), but it's caused some issues for me in the past. What causes this strange behavior? Where is it documented?

It's not strange at all.

A stream is a stream, not a string.

You can obtain the [string] buffer with the member function `.str()`. That's not a workaround: it's the API. It should be documented in your C++ standard library reference, and if it's not then your reference is incomplete/wrong.

(What *is* slightly strange is that you get a memory address rather than a compilation error; that is due to the use of the *safe bool idiom* in the pre-C++0x standard library, as covered in another answer.)

Comment: Well, it's note really the *safe bool* idiom. More like some crippled form of it...

Comment: @Xeo: Well, whatever. It's at least vaguely related. :) Consider that part of my answer non-normative!

Comment: @Xeo: It's still safer than `operator bool` in C++03 :)

Comment: Pack it inside a `[ Note: ... -end note ]`. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: I almost did, but the 5 minute window had passed and I don't want my answer to appear edited :P

Answer (score 2):

A `std::stringstream` is not supposed to be inserted in a stream. That's why you have the `str()` method.

The behavior you're observing is due to the fact that `std::stringstream` has a conversion to `void*`, which is what is used to test the stream:

```
if(Foo) { // this uses the conversion to void*
}
```

In C++11, this conversion is replaced by an explicit conversion to bool, which causes this code not to compile:

```
std::cout << Foo << std::endl;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it compile?  Wouldn't it just output `1` or something?

Comment: No, because the conversion is explicit, meaning you'd have to write `std::cout << bool(Foo);`. Check this other answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242296/conversion-function-for-error-checking-considered-good/6242355#6242355

Answer (score 0):

(1)use std::cout << Foo << std::endl; you should make sure stringstream  has already overload "<<".

(2)if there is not overload "<<" , use std::cout << Foo << std::endl; may output the Foo's address.