# Why doesn't std::weak_ptr<> provide a bool conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

C++11's std::shared_ptr<> provides a kind of bool operator.

```
operator unspecified-bool-type() const;
```

(It's not a straight-up `operator bool() const` due to the [dangers from implicit casting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2435.htm) of type `bool`.)

Why doesn't std::weak_ptr<> have a similar operator? I find myself constantly typing

```
if( !wp.expired() )
```

when I want to type

```
if( wp )
```

Why no bool conversion for weak_ptr?

Comment: Because features are not implemented by default?

Comment: `operator bool` can now be safely done straight-up in C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242355/46642

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`if(!wp.expired())` is almost always a wrong check in multithreaded code, because directly after that `if` statement the pointer could expire. As such, if `weak_ptr` had exactly that as the semantics for the `bool` conversion, it would never be used anyways.

If you want to check if the pointer is alive, use `lock` and check the obtained `shared_ptr`.

If you want to know if the pointer is dead, use `expired`.

As you can see, it just doesn't make sense to provide a boolean conversion. For `shared_ptr`, it totally does. Btw, the conversion operator is `explicit operator bool() const noexcept;` in C++11.

Comment: "*If you want to check if the pointer is alive, use lock and check the obtained shared_ptr.*" Dangerous because you might wind up discarding the last strong pointer to the object, so you could only do this in a context in which it was safe to invoke the object's destructor.

Comment: I would suggest that any context is safe to invoke any object's destructor, because destructors should be written in such a way that they may be safely called at any time (AIUI, this needs to be the case for exception handling to work in the general case, as stack unwinding could destruct any arbitrary object). I'd be interested in a counterexample though.

Comment: Well, there are objects, whose destructor might throw or cause unwanted side effects. But such objects should never be wrapped inside a `shared_ptr` in the first place.

Comment: _it just doesn't make sense to provide a boolean conversion_: I disagree. If I want to check if the `weak_ptr` is empty, e.g. default constructed, the proper semantic is the one of `operator bool`. Using `expired` semantically implies that it was once valid.

Comment: This answer is overly opinionated and prescriptive. I wanted a simple bool conversion because I needed to add a sanity check assertion at a point in the program where the weak_ptr absolutely must be valid (enforces certain other preconditions).