# Evaluate struct as a bool

Tags: c++

I'm stuck on evaluating a struct as a bool in c++

```
struct foo {
  int bar;
};
foo* x = (foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
int y = ( x ) ? 3 : 4;
```

This is what happens when it is ran:

```
could not convert 'x' from 'foo' to 'bool'
```

When searching for bool operators, I can only find ways to overload the comparator bool operator.  Is there a straight up evaluate struct as a bool operator?

I also want to keep foo as plain old data if possible.

Comment: Use `operator bool()`? Of course what you've shown tests the pointer.

Comment: That's a pointer to a struct, not a struct itself. It should work, what compiler are you using?

Comment: You get this when it's run (rather that compiled)? How exactly do you run this?

Comment: I can't imagine the code you posted giving the error you claim. You want `( *x )`, not `( x )`.

Comment: You are missing an asterisk somewhere: `could not convert 'x' from 'foo' to 'bool'` error comes from some place else, because `x` is `foo*`, not `foo`.

Comment: Sorry it errors in compilation.

Comment: Because he's new to programming. Don't need bool operator, just make sure X is indeed declared as a pointer in the code, so the nullptr check is working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't be the correct code for that error. The error states that it can't convert `x` from `foo` to `bool`, but `x` is *not* a `foo`, it is a `foo*`. And a `foo*` *is* convertable to bool<sup>1</sup>, so there would be no error for the code you have given.

If you want to be able to use a `foo` object as a conditional, you need to provide `operator bool` member function for your `foo` class:

```
struct foo {
  int bar;
  operator bool() { return true; }
};
foo x;
int y = x ? 3 : 4;
```

In this case, any `foo` will always evaluate to `true`. This conversion to `bool` is considered "unsafe" because your object may be converted to `bool` in some unexpected places. To get around this, in C++03 you can use the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool) and in C++11 you can mark your `operator bool` as `explicit`:

```
struct foo {
  int bar;
  explicit operator bool() { return true; }
};
```

The `explicit operator bool` will still be used automatically in certain places, such as as a condition in `if` statements and `while` loops. There are [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242355/150634) that cover this.

---

> <sup>1</sup> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.

Comment: You should probably also mention why it is generally really bad practice to implement the conversion-to-bool operation using T::operator bool() as well.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that defining an operator on a struct would preserve it's POD status.

Answer (score 6):

There is no straight-up evaluate-struct-as-a-bool operator. That's *why* there's a way to *give* a struct an `operator bool` method. It tells the compiler how to interpret a value of the given struct type when it's used in a `bool` context.

The code you've shown would not use such an operator, though, since the operator applies to *structs*, not *pointers* to structs; you have an expression of type `foo*`, not `foo`. Pointers automatically convert to `bool` because that's an intrinsic conversion the compiler knows how to perform. Null pointers are false, and non-null pointers are true. The code shown in the question would never yield the reported error message.

If you do indeed have a struct in a place where the compiler expects a `bool`, and you cannot, for whatever reason, give the struct an `operator bool` method, then you can perform the conversion the old-fashioned way and use an ordinary function:

```
bool interpret_foo_as_bool(foo const& f);
```

Implement the function however you want, and then call it, passing your `foo` value. For example:

```
foo* x = ...;
int y = interpret_foo_as_bool(*x) ? 3 : 4;
```