# implicit conversions from and to class types

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am studying converting constructors and conversion operators in C++.
What I've learned so far is that any non-explicit constructor that takes only one parameter (and any number of optional default arguments) represents an implicit class-type conversion to THAT class type, for example if a class defines a constructor that has one parameter of type `int` I can use an `int` wherever an object of that class type is required:

(assuming class_type has an overloaded += operator)

```
class_type a;
a+=5;
```

in this case 5 is implicitly converted (through the converting constructor) to `class_type`and the overloaded operator is called.

Now, the (at least for me) tricky part: I know I can define a conversion operator as a member function :

```
operator int() {....};
```

that converts the object of `class_type` to the primitive `int` type, and I can use that conversion like:

```
class_type a;
a+5;
```

in this case I've read that the object is converted to an int through its conversion operator and then the buil-in sum operator is called.
But what if I defined an overloaded + operator to take two class_type objects as its arguments? something like

`class_type operator+(const class_type&,const class_type &c);`

how is the compiler supposed to know which one to call through function matching?
does the conversion to `int` only happens implicitly when only the built-in operator is defined?

thanks!

edit:

actually,I've tried to write some code to effectively try it out, it turned out that my compiler (g++) doesn't issue any ambiguous call error!

this is the class header (along with the non-memeber operator+ function declaration) :

```
#include <iostream>

class wrapper {
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&,const wrapper&);
  public:
    wrapper()=default; 
    wrapper(int);
    int get();
    operator int() const;
    wrapper operator+(int);
  private:
    int a=10;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream&,const wrapper&);
```

and this is the main code:

```
#include "wrapper.h"

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  wrapper w1;
  wrapper w2(5);
  cout<<w1<<" "<<w2<<endl;
  w1+1;  
}
```

now,I've defined a converting constructor from `int` to `wrapper` AND a conversion operator from class type to `int`(I've also overloaded the << output operator in order to print some results), but when the compiler evaluates the expression `w1+1` it seems to be fine. How could it possibly be??

Comment: Maybe reading [this implicit conversions reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) might help?

Comment: Also, for the `a+=5` example I assume you mean that you overloaded `operator+=` taking `class_type` as argument? Because it could just as easily have been an overload taking an `int`.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, having both implicit constructors and implicit conversion operators confuses not only the compiler but human readers as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have for example the following class declaration that contains a conversion constructor and a conversion operator

```
struct A
{
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
    operator int() const { return x; }
    int x;
};        

const A operator +( const A &a1, const A &a2 )
{
    return A( a1.x + a2.x );
}
```

then statement

```
a1 + a2;
```

where a1 and a2 are declared like for example

```
A a1( 10 );
A a2( 20 );
```

will be well-formed because there is no need to call a conversion function. The both operands match the parameter declarations of the operator +.

However if you will write for example

```
a1 + 20;
```

when the compiler issues an error because there is an ambiguity. The compiler can either apply conversion constructor `A( int )`  to convert the second operand to type `A` and call the operator defined for objects of type `A`. Or it can apply the conversion operator `operator int` to convert the first operand to type `int` and call the built-in `operator +` for objects of type `int`.

To avoid this ambiguity you could declare either the constructor or the operator (or the both) with function specifier `explicit`.

For example

```
    explicit A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
```

or

```
    explicit operator int() const { return x; }
```

In this case only one implicit conversion would exist and there was not an ambigiuty.

I would like to append the above description that sometimes some converion operators can be called implicitly even if they are declared with the function specifier `explicit`.

For example According to the C++ Standard (6.4 Selection statements)

> 4. ...The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the 
>      expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other
>      than switch;

and (5.16 Conditional operator)

> 1 Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is
>   contextually converted to bool (Clause 4).

So for example if the above class has the following conversion operator declared with the function specifier `explicit`

```
explicit operator bool() const { return x != 0; }
```

nevertheless it will be called implicitly for example in the following statement

```
A a( 10 );

std::cout << ( a ? "true" : "false" ) << std::endl;
```

Here a will be converted to an object of type bool in the conditional operator.

EDIT: After you updated your question this expression

```
w1+1;
```

is an exact match for operator

```
wrapper operator+(int);
```

Neither conversion are required. So the code compiles successfully.

Comment: Upvoted for remembering the special case where the `explicit operator bool` would be implicitly called, or [contextually converted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6242355/183120) as the standard calls it.

Comment: @legends2k  You are a kind person!: Could you also upvote my other answers?:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow please can you have a look at my edits? thanks a lot!

Comment: @Luca See my updated post. Take into account that it is a good idea do not change questions after they were answered. Otherwise  they can confuse readers.

Answer (score 3):

This is something you can easily try and see what the compiler does:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ABC {
    int v;
    ABC(int x) : v(x) { }
    operator int() const { return v; }
    void operator +=(ABC const &that) {
        v += that.v;
    }
};

ABC operator+(ABC const &lhs, ABC const &rhs) {
    return { lhs.v + rhs.v };
}

int main() {
    ABC a(5);
    std::cout << a + 1 << '\n';
    a += 10;
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

> what if I defined an overloaded + operator to take two class_type objects as its arguments?

GCC

> error: ambiguous overload for 'operator+' (operand types are 'ABC' and 'int')

The compiler sees two candidates: `operator+(int, int) <built-in>` and `ABC operator+(const ABC&, const ABC&)`. This means it could implicitly convert not only the `5` in `a + 5` to `a` but also the `a` to `int`. Post these conversions both `operator+` functions become potential matches.

> How is the compiler supposed to know which one to call through function matching?

It doesn't know hence the error.

> does the conversion to `int` only happens implicitly when only the built-in operator is defined?

Yes, otherwise it doesn't automatically convert `class_type` to `int`. However, `int` to `class_type` would happen implicitly unless you make `class_type`'s constructor `explicit`:

```
explicit ABC(int x) : v(x) { }
```

If you've access to C++11, then you also make the conversion function explicit:

```
explicit operator int() const { return v; }
```