# How can std::cin return a bool and itself at the same time?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm reading a book on C++ that says that if I use the >> operator it returns the object at the left side of the operator so in this example

> ```
> std::cin >> value1;
> ```

the code returns `std::cin`.

But if I do this

```
while(std::cin >> value1)
```

My code will be in the loop until there is a `std::cin` error so that must mean that the operator returns a `bool` that is true when `std::cin` does not fail and false when `std::cin` fails.

Which is one is it?

Comment: `std::cin` also has a conversion operator to `bool` which is used in the condition.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Comments are for comments, not answers.

Answer (score 55):

> [...] so that must mean that the operator returns a bool  [...]

Nope, it returns `std::cin` (by reference). The reason why `while(std::cin >> value);` works is because `std::istream` (which is the type of `std::cin`) has a [**conversion operator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

A conversion operator basically permits a class to be implicitly (if it is not marked `explicit`) to be converted to a given type. In this case, `std::istream` defines its `operator bool` to return whether an error (typically `failbit`) occurred;

<sub>[`[std::ios_base::operator bool()]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)</sub>

> Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

---

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

Note than even though the operator is `explicit` (which shouldn't allow implicit conversions like `if (std::cin);`), the qualifier is ignored when used in a context that requires a `bool`, like `if`, `while` loops and `for` loops. Those are exceptions though, not rules.

Here is an example:

```
if (std::cin >> value);  //OK, a 'std::istream' can be converted into a 'bool', which 
                         //therefore happens implicitly, without the need to cast it: 

if (static_cast<bool>(std::cin >> value)); //Unnecessary

bool b = std::cin >> value;  //Error!! 'operator bool' is marked explicit (see above), so 
                             //we have to call it explicitly:

bool b = static_cast<bool>(std::cin >> value); //OK, 'operator bool' is called explicitly
```

Comment: This might be less confusing for the OP if you point out that a simple `void* ptr = NULL: if (ptr)` also works (with which he or she is surely familiar), because it's _convertibility_ to `bool` that's important, rather than the actual expression having `bool` type originally.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good idea :) But it might be better *without* `void*, it is supposed to be avoided.

Comment: I think in addition to the exceptions from the rule it'd be useful to add a non-exception like `bool good=std::cin;`, which rightly doesn't compile.

Comment: @Ruslan Good idea :)

Comment: Great explanation. Instead of describing "exceptions" at all, it may be simpler to state that putting any expression in an `if` or `while` condition *is* a rather explicit cast to bool.

Answer (score 22):

`std::istream` (the class which `std::cin` is an object of) has the following member function:

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

It returns false if the object is in an error state, and true otherwise. This is why the `while(std::cin >> value1)` construct works. Before C++11, it had this non explicit function instead:

```
operator void*() const;
```

Which returned a null pointer if the object was in an error state, serving the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

`std::cin` is of type `std::istream` (which is just a `typedef` of [`std::basic_istream<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream))

If you see the [different overloaded `operator>>` for `basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), all of them are returning a reference to `basic_istream`. So one thing is cleared up that the `operator>>` here, doesn't return a `bool` but instead, it returns "`std::cin`" itself. You won't see any `operator>>` there returning a `bool` value.

So the question is now, how does it convert the `std::basic_istream` to `bool`?
The answer is: A *conversion operator* is being called for this purpose.

`std::basic_istream` inherits a [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) from its parent `std::basic_ios`

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

which makes it possible to convert a `std::basic_istream` object to `bool`.
One can easily wonder that it is marked `explicit` (see [why is it marked `explicit`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2333.html)) and still it is implicitly converted to `bool` in an `if` or `while`.

The answer to this question is that `if` or `while` use the explicit conversion "implicitly". (see [this answer by @R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242296/conversion-function-for-error-checking-considered-good/6242355#6242355)). So `if`, `while` and `for` are one of the places where this "*contexual conversion*" to `bool` happens implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

**Operations on streams return a reference to the stream.**

So, not a `bool`.

You can stick the result into an `if` condition for the same reason that you can do this:

```
void* ptr = foo();
if (ptr) { /*...*/ }
```

And, for that matter, this:

```
int x = foo();
if (x) { /*...*/ }
```

Both `ptr` and `x` here can be *converted* to a `bool` for use in the condition. In the case of `std::cin`, the conversion is achieved by an `operator bool()` within the `std::ostream` class that was explicitly (pun intended) added for this exact task.