# How does c++ nullptr implementation work?

Tags: c++, c++17, nullptr, null-pointer

I am curious to know how `nullptr` works. Standards N4659 and N4849 say:

1. it has to have type `std::nullptr_t`;
2. you cannot take its address;
3. it can be directly converted to a pointer and pointer to member;
4. `sizeof(std::nullptr_t) == sizeof(void*)`;
5. its conversion to `bool` is `false`;
6. its value can be converted to integral type identically to `(void*)0`, but not backwards;

So it is basically a constant with the same meaning as `(void*)0`, but it has a different type. I have found the implementation of `std::nullptr_t` on my device and it is as follows.

```
#ifdef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_NULLPTR

_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD

struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS nullptr_t
{
    void* __lx;

    struct __nat {int __for_bool_;};

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR nullptr_t() : __lx(0) {}
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR nullptr_t(int __nat::*) : __lx(0) {}

    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR operator int __nat::*() const {return 0;}

    template <class _Tp>
        _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR
        operator _Tp* () const {return 0;}

    template <class _Tp, class _Up>
        _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
        operator _Tp _Up::* () const {return 0;}

    friend _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR bool operator==(nullptr_t, nullptr_t) {return true;}
    friend _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR bool operator!=(nullptr_t, nullptr_t) {return false;}
};

inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR nullptr_t __get_nullptr_t() {return nullptr_t(0);}

#define nullptr _VSTD::__get_nullptr_t()

_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD

#else  // _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_NULLPTR

namespace std
{
    typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;
}

#endif  // _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_NULLPTR
```

I am more interested in the first part though. It seems to satisfy the points 1-5, but I have no idea why it has a subclass __nat and everything related to it. I would also like to know why it fails on integral conversions.

```
struct nullptr_t2{
    void* __lx;
    struct __nat {int __for_bool_;};
     constexpr nullptr_t2() : __lx(0) {}
     constexpr nullptr_t2(int __nat::*) : __lx(0) {}
     constexpr operator int __nat::*() const {return 0;}
    template <class _Tp>
         constexpr
        operator _Tp* () const {return 0;}
    template <class _Tp, class _Up>
        operator _Tp _Up::* () const {return 0;}
    friend  constexpr bool operator==(nullptr_t2, nullptr_t2) {return true;}
    friend  constexpr bool operator!=(nullptr_t2, nullptr_t2) {return false;}
};
inline constexpr nullptr_t2 __get_nullptr_t2() {return nullptr_t2(0);}
#define nullptr2 __get_nullptr_t2()

int main(){
    long l  = reinterpret_cast<long>(nullptr);
    long l2 = reinterpret_cast<long>(nullptr2); // error: invalid type conversion
    bool b  = nullptr; // warning: implicit conversion
                       // edditor error: a value of type "std::nullptr_t" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "bool"
    bool b2 = nullptr2;
    if (nullptr){}; // warning: implicit conversion
    if (nullptr2){};
};
```

Comment: `nullptr_t` is a fundamental type.  How is `int` implemented?

Comment: Note `#ifdef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_NULLPTR`. This seems like a best-effort workaround for when the compiler doesn't provide `nullptr`.

Comment: @L.F. Similar to how `float` is implemented

Comment: *nullptr* is not guaranteed to be implemented, it can have a special definition like the one in the code.

Comment: @Fullfungo The standard says that `nullptr_t` is a fundamental type.  Implementing it as a class type does not make a conforming implementation.  See chris's comment.

Comment: Related: [safe bool idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242355/9716597) [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/9716597)

Comment: @L. F. Ok, makes sense. I still want to know what `__nat` does and why it is there, maybe this will help me in my own code.

Comment: @L.F. Does the standard technically require that a fundamental type is not a class type?

Comment: @Fullfungo it's basically used for the pre-C++11 [safe bool idiom](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).  A simple `operator bool` will allow it to be converted to, say, `int` or class types constructible from `bool`.

Comment: @eerorika Wow, I always assumed that to be true before, but seems the closest I can find is a [note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#1) that says "There are two kinds of types: fundamental types and compound types" ...

Comment: @eerorika: `is_class` and `is_null_pointer` cannot both be true for the same type. [Only one of the primary type category functions can return true for a specific type.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/meta.unary.cat#3)

Comment: @NicolBolas In simple words: Primitive types and User-defined types are mutually exclusive classifications

Comment: @NicolBolas, Could the implementation _technically_ special-case it so those still return correct results?

Comment: @chris: It's version of `is_class` and `is_null_pointer` could lie, making an explicit exception for this `std::nullptr_t` type by returning "incorrect" values.

Comment: If it helps, the `nullptr` keyword is very similar to the `true` and `false` keywords: all are literals which represent values, for a type which has very few values in the first place. There are only two `bool` values, and only one `std::nullptr_t` value.

Comment: @chris The implementation can do any kinds of "cheats" it likes to get behavior of conforming programs to act like the imaginary C++ "virtual machine", per the "as if" rule (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.abstract#1 and footnote).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I am curious to know how nullptr works.

It works in the simplest way possible: by *fiat*. It works because the C++ standard *says* it works, and it works the way it does because the C++ standard says that implementations must *make it work* in that fashion.

It's important to recognize that it is *impossible* to implement `std::nullptr_t` using the rules of the C++ language. The conversion from a null pointer constant of type `std::nullptr_t` to a pointer is not a user-defined conversion. That means that you can go from a null pointer constant to a pointer, then through a user-defined conversion to some other type, all in a single implicit conversion sequence.

That's not possible if you implement `nullptr_t` as a class. Conversion operators represent user-defined conversions, and C++'s implicit conversion sequence rules don't allow for more than one user-defined conversion in such a sequence.

So the code you posted is a nice approximation of `std::nullptr_t`, but it is nothing more than that. It is not a legitimate implementation of the type. This was probably from an older version of the compiler (left in for backwards-compatibility reasons) before the compiler provided proper support for `std::nullptr_t`. You can see this by the fact that it `#define`s `nullptr`, while C++11 says that `nullptr` is a *keyword*, not a macro.

C++ cannot implement `std::nullptr_t`, just as C++ cannot implement `int` or `void*`. Only the implementation can implement those things. This is what makes it a "fundamental type"; it's a part of the *language*.

---

> its value can be converted to integral type identically to (void*)0, but not backwards;

There is [no implicit conversion](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv#ptr) from a null pointer constant to integral types. There is a conversion from `0` to an integral type, but that's because it's the integer literal zero, which is... an integer.

`nullptr_t` can be *cast* to an integer type (via `reinterpret_cast`), but it can only be implicitly converted to pointers and to `bool`.

Comment: What is meant by "it is impossible to implement std::nullptr_t using the rules of the C++ language"? Does it mean a C++ compiler cannot be completely written in C++ itself (I'm guessing not)?

Comment: @northerner: I mean that you cannot write a type that is exactly equivalent to the behavior required of `std::nullptr_t`. Just as you cannot write a type that is exactly equivalent to the behavior required of `int`. You can get close, but there will still be significant differences. And I'm not talking about trait detectors like `is_class` that expose that your type is user-defined. There are things about the required behavior of fundamental types that you simply cannot copy by using the rules of the language.

Comment: Just a wording quibble. When you say "C++ cannot implement `nullptr_t`" you speak too broadly. And saying "only the implementation can implement it" only confuses matters.  What you mean is that `nullptr_t` cannot be implemented" **in the C++ library** because it's part of the base language.

Comment: @Spencer: No, I meant exactly what I said: C++ the language cannot be used to implement a type that does everything that `std::nullptr_t` is required to do. Just as C++ the language cannot implement a type that does everything that `int` is required to do.

Comment: You did not say "C++ cannot be used to implement", you said "C++ cannot implement". If you edit your answer to say the former rather than the latter, I will be OK with that.

Comment: @Spencer: From the first sentence, second paragraph: "it is impossible to implement std::nullptr_t using the rules of the C++ language." Context matters.

Comment: And I'm not contradicting that. I just want you to word it better in your answer, because words matter.

Answer (score 0):

`nullptr` is a fundamental type, it's part of the C++ language implementation. Unlike to `NULL` keyword which is a macro evaluated in integer constant `0`, the `nullptr` is actually a keyword implying pointer literal. As `int` is actually a builtin type in the language of size 4 byte (x64), `nullptr` is also a builtin type of size 8 byte (x64)

Comment: so you mean `nullptr_t` is type of a builtin type?